# Create sample database backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We, like many businesses, have a live environment and a development environment. For reasons beyond my control, the dev environment does not have the capacity to store everything from the live environment. As such, when the dev env needs to be refreshed, the DBA has to manually copy a sample of each table (the last 6 months of data, for example).

Does anyone know of a way this can be automated? I'm aware there is such a thing as a partial backup but that's about backing up different filegroups. Differential backups are also no good because although alot of our data is readonly we need more than just the data that has changed.

EDIT: Just rereading this, and I should clarify that we also don't have time to write a lengthy bespoke script to do the task :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you want to back up prod to dev ?

Comment: If you're doing this for *each* table in the database, and each table has a date key, you can iterate sys.tables & just generate the insert statements. Avoids you having to write lenghty scripts defining all tables. Just keep in mind some tables might require identity insert as well.

Comment: You can read about [SSIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) and create package to copy down your data and schedule that package run as you need.

Comment: Thomas - Yeah, but ideally with some form of tablesampling.
Jens - This has crossed my mind, but again requires dev time that management are not willing to sign off on :/ Part of me was hoping that someone might come out with some hitherto unknown bulk insert/backup syntax that would work like the table sample hint! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Snapshot replication could be an option. 
You could put filters on the different articles (tables) to replicate just the sample of data across. 
Script this on the first run, and then re-use again.

Next step would be to schedule these scripts to run weekly/monthly (period that you want it refreshed).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should generate you the insert statements in case you were going to create something anyways. Just from the top of my head though, so untested.

```
DECLARE @v_SourceDatabase      NVARCHAR(250); 
DECLARE @v_DestinationDatabase NVARCHAR(250);
DECLARE @t_TablesToProcess     TABLE (FullTableName NVARCHAR(250),
                                      TableName     NVARCHAR(250),
                                      TableSchema   NVARCHAR(250),
                                      ColumnList    NVARCHAR(MAX));
DECLARE @v_ColumnList         NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @v_TableName          NVARCHAR(250);
DECLARE @v_TableSchema        NVARCHAR(250);

-- -------------------------------------- --
-- Set Source & destination database here --
-- -------------------------------------- --

SET @v_SourceDatabase      = N'DatabaseSource';
SET @v_DestinationDatabase = N'DatabaseDestination';

-- Generate tables to process
INSERT INTO @t_TablesToProcess
SELECT CONCAT('[', syssch.name, '].[', systab.name, ']') FullTableName
     , systab.name
     , syssch.name
     , NULL
FROM   sys.tables systab
INNER JOIN sys.schemas syssch
  ON syssch.schema_id = systab.schema_id
WHERE type = 'U';

DECLARE TableList CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
  SELECT TableName, TableSchema
  FROM @t_TablesToProcess;

OPEN TableList;
FETCH NEXT FROM TableList INTO @v_TableName, @v_TableSchema;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SELECT @v_ColumnList = CONCAT(@v_ColumnList, N'[', column_name, N'], ')
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = @v_TableName
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @v_TableSchema

  SET @v_ColumnList = LEFT(@v_ColumnList, LEN(@v_ColumnList) - 1);

  UPDATE @t_TablesToProcess
  SET ColumnList = @v_ColumnList
  WHERE TableName = @v_TableName
    AND TableSchema = @v_TableSchema;

  SET @v_ColumnList = '';

    FETCH NEXT FROM TableList INTO @v_TableName, @v_TableSchema;
END 

CLOSE TableList;
DEALLOCATE TableList;

-- Generate insert statements
SELECT CONCAT(N'IF (OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(''', FullTableName, '''), ''TableHasIdentity'') = 1) SET IDENTITY_INSERT ', FullTableName, N' ON; '
            , N'INSERT INTO [', @v_DestinationDatabase, N'].', FullTableName
            , N' (', ColumnList, N')'
            , N' SELECT * FROM [', @v_SourceDatabase, N'].', FullTableName, N';'
            , N' IF (OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(''', FullTableName, '''), ''TableHasIdentity'') = 1) SET IDENTITY_INSERT ', FullTableName, N' OFF; ')
FROM @t_TablesToProcess;
```

Comment: Thanks @Jens. Appreciate the effort here! I'll use this as a starting point and develop it to suit our needs when I have time.